# identify which textFormField getting error?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have multiple textFormField on the page. Is it possible to identify which textForm got error?

I create custom Text Form Field

```
            CustomTextField(
              controller: oneLineDes
              validator: validatePhone),
```

I create mixin for validation

```
class ValidationMixin {

  String validatePhone(String value){
    String patttern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{9,12}$)';
    RegExp regExp = RegExp(patttern);
    if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Please enter valid Phone Number';
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

onPressed looks like this

```
 onPressed: () {
         if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
}}
```

I need like this:

```
 if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
 }else{
    if(phoneError){
     //show snackBar
    }

    if(emailError){
    //show snackBar
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `key:` property of `TextFormField` with `ValueKey(unique identification number for your widget)`